# MYSQLI_NUM_ROWS doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table called "users" with 1 row. 
I have been trying to get the number of rows that exist when the username and password have been entered. This wasn't returning anything, so I have created this code in the most simple form, but still it is not returning anything.

If I run the query on phpmyadmin, it returns the row.

Why could this not be working?

```
include("../includes/db.php");
$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM users");
die(mysqli_num_rows($result));
```

The connection to the database is fine, all the other code works fine on my CMS.

edit:

This is my now working code:

```
include("../includes/db.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
        $result = $link->query($sql);
        if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
            echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
            LoginForm();
        } else {
            echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        }
    }else{
        LoginForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: because of `Note: PHP >= 4.2.0 does NOT print the status if it is an integer.` die is not good for debuging... http://at1.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: Also, why not use the OOP version to echo your rows: `echo $result->num_rows;` since you are using OOP to query?

Comment: @Rasclatt I tried that too but it didn't make any difference

Comment: @Rufinus How can I print it?

Comment: `die(print_r(mysqli_num_rows($result),1));` for example, or `var_dump(mysli_num_rows($result)); exit;`

Comment: It prints, but I can't do an IF statement with it.

Comment: Show us the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include("../includes/db.php");
$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM users");
echo $result->num_rows;
```

My bad for the previous answer. It's been a while since I've used PHP

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::execute(

Comment: Updated, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks. I see it works now. Although seems I can't do much with the result. `if($result->num_rows >=1){` gives error

Comment: Could you post the error? Might be worth marking the answer as correct here, creating a new question then commenting the link here.

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I remember this being very simple with mysql

Comment: Are you sure it's that line that's causing the error? The only potential issue I see is the no space before the 1. Yeah, mysql was easier... That's why it was so vulnerable.

Comment: @MRC "Trying to get property of non-object" - that means your query failed. Mr. E's answer works, which returned `1` in my test. Add `or die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');` More specifically `$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM users") or die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');`